# Django form override ForeignKey queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-managers

I was making a form for creation unpublished `Artist` instances and then adding `Artwork` to the artist before publishing.

I have manager to hide `published=False` artists and do not know how to bypass this yet in `ForeignKey`.

models.py

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    """Returns only published Artists in queryset"""
    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(VisibleManager, self).get_query_set()
        qs = qs.filter(status='published')
        return qs

class Artist(models.Model):
    objects = PublishedManager() # Used overall on the site to hide published=False objects
    admin_objects = models.Manager() # Default manager Will be used in admin to show invisible     objects too

class Artwork(models.Model):
    artist= models.ForeignKey(Artist)
```

forms.py

```
class ArtworkForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArtworkForm,self).__init(args,kwargs)
        from django.db import models
        self.fields['artist'].queryset = Artist.admin_objects.all()
```

shell

```
>>> form=Artwork_form(artist=180) #unpublished artist pk
>>> form.errors

Model artist with pk 180 does not exist
```

**I need to make the form "see" the unpublished artists in FK, how can i achieve this?**

Thank you.

Comment: What you have in the ArtworkForm.__init__ should work if it's after the call to super. Can you show us the full method? Also can you show the stacktrace to the Artist.DoesNotExist error?

Comment: @schillingt, Thank you, I forgot to include `super()` line from source. This is the only stack trace i have, creation of the form produces this error message enclosed with `<ul><li></li</ul>` tags i ommited in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution!!!

Original info is here http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/custom-managers-django-foreignkeys/

I implemented the `CustomManagerForeignKey` as the autor of this post had written with the one exception(otherwise in won't work properly):

usage:

```
class Artwork(models.Model):
    artist= CustomManagerForeignKey(Artist, manager=Artist.admin_objects)
```

and a fix for this in the `CustomManagerForeignKey`:

```
class CustomManagerForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'manager' in kwargs:
            self.customManager = kwargs['manager'] #Here i removed the () in the end of the line
            del kwargs['manager']
        else:
            self.customManager = None
        super(CustomManagerForeignKey, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```